# Trigger to reshape phonenumber

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, plpgsql

I want a trigger is my database which changes the first zero of a phone number to the appropriate country-code (in my case it's +31). My code so far is:

```
create or replace function correct_number()
    returns trigger as $$
declare 
    Pnumber integer;
begin
    select substring(phone, 1, 1) from "user" where phone = new.phone into Pnumber;
    if Pnumber = 0 then 
            update "user"
            set phone = overlay("user".phone placing '+31' from 1 for 1)
            where id = new.id;
        return null;
    end if;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger force_countrynr
before insert on "user"
for each statement execute procedure correct_number();
```

There problem is that every time I try to add data, my DBMS gives an error that the end of the procedure is reached without a return. This means obviously that it doesn't consider the if-statement to be true, but I can't figure out why.

This is the DDL of the attribute that my function concerns is a varchar(13) and the my testquery is as follows:

```
insert into gebruiker
values('U5', 'Hans', '12345', 'Hans', null, 'Kraay', 'Hansworst', '0000QW', 'beukenweg', '4', null, '0612345678', 'test@notnow.nl', '2015-12-12');
```

I've tried changing the datatype of the zero in my if-statement, changing the datatype of the number-variable and many things more, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: It is better to just check if data are valid. Sometimes are triggers too transparent, and when you modify data, then you can prepare some future issue. This is application task. use triggers for it only if you cannot to do in application. Or write explicit function for purpose and call it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to correct the number in each inserted row, so the trigger should be `for each row`.

There is no reason to query the table in the trigger, as the currently inserted row is available in the `new` variable.

There is no reason to update the table, just modify the `new` record and return it.

```
create or replace function correct_number()
    returns trigger as $$
begin
    if left(new.phone, 1) = '0' then
        new.phone:= '+31' || right(new.phone, -1);
    end if;
    return new;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger force_countrynr
before insert on "user"
for each row execute procedure correct_number();
```

Comment: doesn't 'for each row' mean that it will update every row, on every insert in the relation?

Comment: No, it means that the trigger is fired for every inserted row.